# How can I use query_posts to loop through posts and construct my own content?

Tags: posts, query-posts

I am using query_posts to combine two posts categories on a page (by inserting this simple php script on the page using a plugin). This script gives me all the posts I want, however one of the categories has some extra custom fields using another plugin (CFS). The plugin has an api to get all fields and values by post id, I want to be able to loop through the wp posts array and add the custom fields where appropriate but I don't know much about wordpress and all the options and different ways of doing the same thing are confusing. I tried to use a wp_query but couldnt get it to work. Is it possible to use query_posts to not automatically add to the webpage but loop through the items so I can add some extra elements?

Edit: To clarify, I am looking for an alternate way to display the posts than add_post_content. I would like to basically make my own version of it, but in each loop also check for the extra fields and add those where appropriate. Is there an alternate to add_post_content like that/a way to get an array of posts rather than display the posts?

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1);

 //adds all posts to page. Is there a way to get the posts but not add to page automatically?
$posts = query_posts( array( 'category__in' => array(152,1), 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'DATE', 'order' => 'DESC', 'paged' => $paged,) );

foreach ($posts as $post){

    if($posts->cat_id = $target_category){ //pseudocode, if post category is cat with extra fields

        $fields = CFS()->get( False, $post->ID); //this line gives array of meta fields and values. 

         add_fields_to_div(); //pseudocode, if target cat add custom field data

       }

    add_post_content(); //add the content from $post
}

the_posts_pagination( ); //paginate
```

Comment: Never use `query_posts` under any circumstances, there is never a valid use of it that doesn't have a significantly better alternative. It brings with it a huge number of problems, the biggest of which is that you're doubling the number of database queries. Use the `pre_get_posts` filter if you want to change which posts WordPress displays,  and if you want to fetch posts from the DB for a custom query, use `WP_Query`. Also for what you're doing you don't need to fetch the posts as an array, `get_post` will do, as will `get_the_ID`

Comment: What is `add_post_content()`? There's no function with that name in WordPress.

Comment: woops, I thought my own pseudo-code from last time I posted was the actual function .. I mean the $posts = query_posts .. line 4. add_post_content is supposed to be my version of the function, for each post I want to add the custom fields at the top where they exist and then all the post data afterwards.